# Is there the way to filter loading objects when a viewer starts with Autodesk Forge API?

Tags: autodesk-forge

I want to filter 3d models like walls or windows when a viewer start to load the building model.

I can hide those objects after loading completely with a extension, but I want hide those object before showing the building model.

Is there good way to filter those object?

Comment: As far as I know, Forge Viewer has not yet supported loading partial objects. I am double checking with engineer team if they have any information.

Comment: I got a reply from engineer team that there is a way to load partial objects. What I know is if you set model load option with the array of specific objects Ids, the viewer will load those objects only, e.g. modelOptions={ids:[123,456,789]}; viewer.start(svfUrl,modelOptions).  But engineer team told me it's not particularly efficient, There is no easy way to load additional elements though, you'd have to reload.

Comment: Thank you Xiaodong Liang.

It means we have to get Ids before viewer is set up...it's little bit trouble, but I will try.

Comment: yes, and sorry I just found a typo in the last reply/ . That should be 'I got a reply from engineer team that there is NOT a way to load partial objects'. The way I mentioned is an experimental method which is not official and the ability is very limit. One is what you said 'get dbids in advance, and also no way to load more objects, you have to re-load' . My apology for the limitation of current viewer